# How to dynamically change backgroundimage in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, winforms

Now I'm trying to change dynamically MainForm's backgroundimage.
I wrote that following code segment...

`this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("Bar1.png");
this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;`

Image that I want to change is located in my current project.
But I don't know how to use FromFile Method?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );   



string filename="yourfilename";

this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(path ,filename));
```

or:

```
string customPath = "d:\testpath"; 

string filename="yourfilename";

this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(customPath ,filename));
```

Comment: I'm trying your answer..But that error Occur
URI Format are not supported.

Comment: Can you post the error? If you are in debug make sure your image is in bin/debug folder

Comment: also check, selecting your image in VS, "Copy to output dyrectory" property. Set it to "copy always"

Comment: Have you inspected "path" in debug? What is the value?

Comment: When i tried C:/ProgramsFiles......Bar1.png
Its Okay..
But i want to know how to path photos in my current project
Not C:\.....

Comment: It's not i mean sir.I got like that D:\
I mean ASP.Net , current projects sign is "~" 
I want to know which sign is like that..
No matter what thanks you for your answering

Comment: I see winform tag! Not asp.net! However... in asp.net if you have a path like this: ~/folder/ you can resolve it with Server.MapPath("~/folder/"); HTH

Answer (score 2):

You can get application startup path with this code:

```
Application.StartupPath + "\yourimage"
```

or you can use

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\yourimage";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read documentation about FromFile method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx).

And if you have image in your resource file, you can access it like this:

```
this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.yourImageName;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName);
    this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. make a directory named background where your exe located.
2. copy background jpg file in that directory
3. add following in form load event

   string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\background\";
   string filename="back.jpg";
   this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(path, filename));

if you changed background jpg file keeping same file name, the background will be changed.